# Função pra criptografar e decriptografar no PHP 7+

Tags: php, criptografia

Eu possuo as funções abaixo:

```
function enCript($string, $key) 
{
    $result = '';
    $test = "";
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) 
    {
         $char = substr($string, $i, 1);
         $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
         $char = chr(ord($char)+ord($keychar));

         $test[$char]= ord($char)+ord($keychar);
         $result.=$char;
     }
     return urlencode(base64_encode($result));
  }

function deCript($string, $key) 
{
    $result = '';
    $string = base64_decode(urldecode($string));
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++)
    {
       $char = substr($string, $i, 1);
       $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
       $char = chr(ord($char)-ord($keychar));
       $result.=$char;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

exemplo de uso:

```
echo enCript('201910037', '7636846602');
```

retorna:

> ```
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'd' in $test[$char]= ord($char)+ord($keychar);
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'g' in $test[$char]= ord($char)+ord($keychar);
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'g' in $test[$char]= ord($char)+ord($keychar);
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'l' in $test[$char]= ord($char)+ord($keychar);
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'g' in $test[$char]= ord($char)+ord($keychar);
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'h' in $test[$char]= ord($char)+ord($keychar);
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'd' in $test[$char]= ord($char)+ord($keychar);
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'i' in $test[$char]= ord($char)+ord($keychar);
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'm' in $test[$char]= ord($char)+ord($keychar);
>
> ZGdnbGdoZGlt
> ```

Comment: e qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: me explique o porque de usar esta cript para eu formulá-la pra vc

Comment: Não diretamente relacionado ao seu erro, mas enfim: se isso for apenas um exercício, não tem problema criar seu algoritmo criptográfico. Mas se for usar isso em um sistema real para criptografar informações sensíveis, [**não** invente seu próprio algoritmo](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/915) (leia mais sobre isso [aqui](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/2210) e [aqui](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/25585)).

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando acessar uma `string` como se fosse um `array`, com uma chave que é uma `string`. `String` não vai entender isso. 
No código, podemos ver o problema:

```
"hello"["hello"];
// PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'hello' in php shell code on line 1

"hello"[0];
// Sem erros.

array("hello" => "val")["hello"];
//Sem erros. Isto é *Provavelmente* o que quer.
```

**Vejamos seu erro:**

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'g' in $test[$char]= ord($char)+ord($keychar);

O erro diz que está tentando usar a string 'g' como um índice para uma string.
Por exemplo:

```
$a_string = "string";

// aqui está certo:
echo $a_string[0]; // s
echo $a_string[1]; // t
echo $a_string[2]; // r
// ...

// isto já é errado:
echo $a_string['g'];
// !! Warning: Illegal string offset 'g' in ...
```

Com isto, você precisa rever o seu código neste linha:

```
$char = chr(ord($char)+ord($keychar));
```